# Cut and Paste Blocks of Data underneath first block using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to come up with/find a VBA code that copies blocks of data under my first block. Each block is 19 columns followed by a blank. The number of rows per block can vary.

See my screenshot below:

[image: Excel Workbook]

Therefore, I would like all my data continuous in the first columns `A:S`. Any help is highly appreciated.

I found the following code online, but this only pastes everything into the first column

```
Sub Column()

Dim iLastcol As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim jLastrow As Long
Dim ColNdx As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim ExcludeBlanks As Boolean
Dim mycell As Range

ExcludeBlanks = (MsgBox("Exclude Blanks", vbYesNo) = vbYes)
Set ws = ActiveSheet
iLastcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Alldata").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets.Add.Name = "Alldata"

For ColNdx = 1 To iLastcol

iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColNdx).End(xlUp).Row

Set myRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, ColNdx), _
                   ws.Cells(iLastRow, ColNdx))

If ExcludeBlanks Then
  For Each mycell In myRng
     If mycell.Value <> "" Then
        jLastrow = Sheets("Alldata").Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
                   .End(xlUp).Row
        mycell.Copy
        Sheets("Alldata").Cells(jLastrow + 1, 1) _
           .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      End If
    Next mycell
      Else
       myRng.Copy
          jLastrow = Sheets("Alldata").Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
            .End(xlUp).Row
      mycell.Copy
      Sheets("Alldata").Cells(jLastrow + 1, 1) _
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
   Next

   Sheets("Alldata").Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Delete

   ws.Activate
 End Sub
```

Comment: So, you know the start cell of each block of data.

Comment: I mean yes, all blocks have the same amount of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, addr

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("T1")

    Do
        Set c = c.End(xlToRight)
        If c.Column = Columns.Count Then Exit Do
        addr = c.Address 'strire the address since Cut will move c
        c.CurrentRegion.Cut c.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set c = ActiveSheet.Range(addr) '<< reset c
    Loop


 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more basic than @TimWilliams

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Alldata")

Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, cpyrng As Range

lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 21 To lCol Step 20
        If .Cells(1, i).Value <> "" And .Cells(1, i).Offset(, -1).Value = "" Then

            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Set cpyrng = .Cells(1, i).CurrentRegion

            cpyrng.Cut
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, 1).Offset(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End With
```